# Updated property not shown in .properties using java

Tags: java, properties

I am trying to store key and value pair in properties during server load. After saving, when i checked the .properties file, changes are not there. I am not sure what i missed out.

Not getting any exception or error. updated property changes is not reflected in my .properties file.

My resource file is in "src\main\resources\logintokencache.properties".

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("logintokencache.properties");
    try {
        prop.load(in);
         prop.setProperty("key","value"); // Setting the property

        // Tried using Filewriter to store the properties, not worked
        File configFile = new File("logintokencache.properties");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(configFile);
        prop.store(writer, null);
        writer.close();

        // Tried using FileOutputStream to store the properties, not worked
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("logintokencache.properties");
        prop.store(output, "This is overwrite file");

        // Reloaded the properties and also checked, not worked
        prop.load(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`logintokencache.properties` is stored at your working dir while the file you load is located somewhere at your classpath. So you are loading one file and store it to a different place.

If you are sure that the resource is writeable (that is not always be the case e.g. if it is insight a jar) you can access via

```
File f = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("logintokencache.properties").getFile());
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
prop.store(out, "");
```

Comment: ok thanks, whats the code change is required. please help it out.